# Ho do I add custom Web Host Configuration properties to Visual Studio Debug Project Setup?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, c#-2.0, visual-studio-debugging

I have an IIS Based C#.NET project that I'm working on.  The project requires that a handful of customizations be added to the configuration of the IIS server.  Some application mappings and ISAPI Filters get added.

Further to that, the structure of the project is such that I open the files at a level above the actual home directory of the website itself. So if the home directory is `\project_root\public_html` I open the project in `\project_root`

The problem arises when I try and run Visual Studio 2010's Debug processes.

- the IIS server started via the build process has none of the custom settings we're using
- the Visual Studio project seems to start the webserver in \project_root instead of \public_html (I see a typical IIS dir listing as opposed to the project I'm trying to run)

Is there anyone who knows how to configure custom server settings for a Vistual Studio web project so I can Debug properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider just using IIS - project -> properties -> Web -> "use local IIS" or "use custom web server" (if need to use other DNS name for local box instead of http://localhost).

Comment: I tried but couldn't find the menu options you're talking about.  I tried opening the website from "Local IIS" but the build fails (while the server itself runs fine).  Choosing Website->Start Options->'custom web server' also doesn't work.

Comment: Right click on the project in "solutions view" - there will be "properties".